# Scroll View Not Functioning Properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using following code:
    slidingImageIconView=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];

```
[slidingImageIconScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(110, 90)];

UIButton *iconImageSlide=[[UIButton alloc] init];
[iconImageSlide setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dummy_img.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[slidingImageIconScrollView addSubview:iconImageSlide];
```

but my button is not adding in scroll view, i know i am missing something very silly but please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that you have `slidingImageIconView` and `slidingImageIconScrollView`. Is that a typo? I've left it like that in my examples here.

You need to `initWithFrame` in order to set the button position and size:

```
slidingImageIconView=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];

[slidingImageIconScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(110, 90)];

UIButton *iconImageSlide=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,20)];
[iconImageSlide setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dummy_img.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[slidingImageIconScrollView addSubview:iconImageSlide];
```

If you want to make the button the same size as the image - then the following rearrangement would allow that. Also note that I've used setBackgroundImage instead of setImage. I tend to use setImage to put an 'icon' on the button, but setBackgroundImage for the actual button-image.

```
UIImage* buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dummy_img.jpg"];

slidingImageIconView=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];

[slidingImageIconScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(110, 90)];

UIButton *iconImageSlide=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,buttonImage.size.width,buttonImage.size.height)];
[iconImageSlide setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[slidingImageIconScrollView addSubview:iconImageSlide];
```

Comment: hi again, u know what my scroll view is not scrolling images when i'm adding 25 of them into it..:(

Comment: Have you set the ContentSize to the height of 25 images? You should probably ask a new question for this - and post the code you're using.

Comment: hey i'v fixed it.. thanks again.. it was content size trouble..:)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the frame of the buttonf it has no useful geometry.

Comment: okay but  how can i do so? and as i have set   scroll view content size is it still worthy?

Comment: Cons up a CGRect and pass it to the -initWithFrame: initializer to UIButton.